# Gradle Warning "unspecified depends on libraries but is a jar " while compiling an android module within a custom java library module

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am a newbee in Gradle. I have a simple project structure (shown bellow) having a main android app module, one android module (myandroidlibrary), and one pure java module (myjavalibrary). They have simple dependencies, app -> myjavalibary, and myjavalibary -> myandroidlibrary (pls see fig. below). Gradle files snapshots are also given below.

However, while sync the gradle it produces following error:

```
 D:\MyTestCodes\MyTestApplication\app\build.gradle
 Warning:Module version MyTestApplication:myjavalibrary:unspecified depends on libraries but is a jar
```

Pls help me out! I have spent this whole day to sort it out with no result!

```
MyProject
  - app
  - myjavalibrary  (pure java library)
  - myandroidlibrary (android library)
```

Now the dependency is as follows:

```
"app" depends on -> "myjavalibrary"
"myjavalibrary" depends on -> "myandroidlibrary"
```

Gradle files for each of the modules are as follows:

`build.gradle` for **app**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    // ommitting other detail

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile project(':myjavalibrary')
}
```

---

`build.gradle` for **myjavalibrary**:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':myandroidlibrary')
}
```

---

`build.gradle` for **myandroidlibrary**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {

   //ommiting other detail.

 dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

---

`settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app', ':myjavalibrary', ':myandroidlibrary'
```

---

Now while I sync the gradle files it shows the following error:

```
 D:\MyTestCodes\MyTestApplication\app\build.gradle
 Warning:Module version MyTestApplication:myjavalibrary:unspecified depends on libraries but is a jar
```

Comment: I have a feeling it's the appcompat dependency.  Can you try updating your google repository in the sdk tools, trying different versions, or putting that dependency on another project, like app, and seeing if it breaks there too?

Comment: Shouldn't your library use the `com.android.library` plugin instead of the `com.android.application` one?

Comment: I have the same exact issue, and i'm using the com.android.library plugin.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 8):

Warning is caused by pure-jave `myjavalibrary` module having a dependency on the `myandroidlibrary` one, which is an Android library.

Gradle warns you that a pure-java module doesn't know anything about Android specific stuff of `myandroidlibrary` (like Android resources, assets etc.). By having this dependency (pure-java to android library one) you might lose some stuff you expect to have.

A much cleaner dependency direction would be the one from a android library to a pure-java library. In this case Gradle won't give you any warnings.

Comment: Do you provide some gradle structure for the same or ammendments in above one?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an Android app project from java code, use `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`.

If you want to create a library project from java code, use `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`.

If you want to use pre-built jar files, do not create any project for them. Just add them into the projects, into the `libs` folder, which depend on them. The `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` in the `dependencies` would take care of them.

Comment: If you are using `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`, don't forget to append `@aar` to the end of the `compile` dependency. eg. `compile 'library:version@aar'`